# When is Dúnhere considered to be attacking alone?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

In The Lord of the Rings LCG, [Dúnhere](http://www.lotrlcg.com/Card/Focus/1009) is a hero with a permanent effect:

> Dúnhere can target enemies in the staging area when he attacks alone. When doing so, he gets +1(Attack).

**What does it mean for him to attack "alone"?**

Does it mean that he cannot combine with other attackers when attacking the staging area?

Or does it mean that if you want to use this ability, no other characters may make an attack of any kind? For just you, or for all players?

An example to highlight: There's a Goblin Sniper in the staging area and an Eastern Crows engaging me. May I use (for instance) a Wandering Took to attack the Eastern Crows, and also use Dúnhere's ability to attack the Goblin Sniper?

Answer (score 4):

Lets have a look at the rules. In the combat phase, after resolving the attacks by encountered enemies, it is the players turn to attack with hers/his heroes and allies. To attack a target the player declares the attackers and exhausts them. Then the combined attack strength will be determined and so on. Only encountered enemies can be attacked.

For Dúnhere this means the following. If you select him in the combat phase as an attacker, and he attacks alone, he can also attack enemies in the staging area. As mentioned on the card if he does so, he gets +1 attack. This does not mean that you cannot do other attacks.

See also this [discussion](http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/45740-dunhere-question/).